# Can a row delineator be used to split a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two column dataframe (time, depth). I want query the time column for a values equal to -999999.000 and then split the column at every occurrence of this value and move the data below this row to a new df. I have a clunky soultion by:

```
time depth  
   3.60061646      0.893399119  
   2.60061646      0.893977463  
   1.60061646      0.894550025  
  0.600616455      0.895119905    
   0.00000000      0.895459890  
  -999999.000      -999999.000  
  3.60061646      0.893399119  
   2.60061646      0.893977463  
   1.60061646      0.894550025  
  0.600616455      0.895119905    
   0.00000000      0.895459890  
  -999999.000      -999999.000
  3.60061646      0.893399119  
   2.60061646      0.893977463  
   1.60061646      0.894550025  
  0.600616455      0.895119905    
   0.00000000      0.895459890  
  -999999.000      -999999.000

df_curve.loc[df_curve['time'] == -999999.000]  
df1 = df_curve.iloc[:6]  
df2 = df_curve.iloc[7:12] 
df3 = df_curve.iloc[13:18]
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? In reality my data set is much larger.

Comment: Please add some example with code and what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is close to what you have, but slightly more automated.

```
idx = df['time'][df['time'] == -999999].index[0]

df1 = df.iloc[:idx+1]
df2 = df.iloc[idx+1:]
```

If you need to split by multiple occurrences of a value, use a dictionary:

```
idx = [0] + list(df['time'][df['time'] == -999999].index) + [df.index[-1]+1]
dfs = {k: df.iloc[i:j] for k, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(idx, idx[1:]), 1)}
```

Comment: thanks, this does work. However, in my data set -999999.000 occurs 10 times so I need a solution that will address beyond `index[0]`

Comment: so you want to split by every occurrence of this value? if so, i would update your question to state that.

Comment: thanks again @jpp, this also works. Is there then a way to seperate `dfs`  into seperate data frames?

Comment: yes: `for k, v in dfs.items(): print(k)` or just `df[n]` where `n` is an integer key.

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand. How does that split the filtered data set (dfs) into individual data frames?
(As you can probably tell, I'm pretty new to this)

Comment: `dfs` is a dictionary of dataframes. Try printing `dfs`, each key-value, e.g. `df[1]`, `df[2]`, etc, will hold a different dataframe.

Comment: Awesome. Got it. Thanks so much for your help!